# How to know if a thread uses die in Perl

Tags: multithreading, perl

I am creating Perl threads in a "master" script that call a "slave" perl script through `system` calls. If this is bad, feel free to enlighten me. Sometimes the slave script being called will fail and `die`. How can I know this in the master script so that I can kill the master?

Is there a way I can return a message to the master thread that will indicate the slave completed properly? I understand it is not good practice to use exit in a thread though. Please help.

==================================================================================
Edit:

For clarification, I have about 8 threads that each run once. There are dependencies between them, so I have barriers that prevent certain threads from running before the initial threads are complete.

Also the system calls are done with `tee`, so that might be part of the reason the return value is difficult to get at.
`system("((" . $cmd . " 2>&1 1>&3 | tee -a $error_log) 3>&1) > $log; echo done | tee -a $log"`

Answer (score 2):

The way you have described your problem, I don't think using threads is the way to go. I would be more inclined to fork. Calling 'system' is going to fork anyway.

```
use POSIX ":sys_wait_h";

my $childPid = fork();
if (! $childPid) {
    # This is executed in the parent
    # use exec rather than system, so that the child process is replaced, rather than
    # forking a new subprocess (or maybe even shell) to run your child process
    exec("/my/child/script") or die "Failed to run child script: $!";
}

# Code here is executed in the parent process
# you can find out what happened to the parent process by calling wait
# or waitpid. If you want to be able to continue processing in the
# parent process then call waitpid with second argument WNOHANG

# EG. inside some event loop, do this
if (waitpid($childPid, WNOHANG)) {

    # $? now contains the exit status of child process
    warn "Child had a problem: $?" if $?;

}
```

Comment: The main reason I chose to use threads was because I have dependencies and the need for barriers for certain jobs. Can this be accomplished with fork? I know relatively little about multithreading in Perl.

Comment: Is there any way to have the slave thread return a value to the master thread using `system`?

Answer (score 1):

There is probably CPAN module that is well suited for what you are trying do.  Maybe [Proc::Daemon - Run Perl program(s) as a daemon process.](http://search.cpan.org/~deti/Proc-Daemon-0.14/lib/Proc/Daemon.pod).